# Java: arrays, multiple classes

Tags: java, arrays

I have 3 classes- Car, ParkingLot and Driver. 
In the ParkingLot class, I have a method called parkCar which is supposed to check for the first empty spot and place the car object there:

```
public void parkCar(Car car) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        if (cars[i] == null) {
            cars[i] = car;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Driver class, there is supposed to be a method which calls the parkCar method to put a car object in a parking spot (driver should no longer have the car):

```
public void putCarInParkingSpot(Parkinglot parkingLot) {
    parkingLot.parkCar(this.car);
    this.car = null;   
}
```

Finally, I have a showParkingLot method in the ParkingLot class which is supposed to show all cars in the array:

```
public void showParkingLot() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        if (cars[i] != null) {
            System.out.println(cars[i].getModel());
        }
    }
}
```

When I use showParkingLot, the 1 car object gets placed in every spot in the array (prints it out 15 times), not just the first null spot(cars[0]). Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a parking is done you need to break, see below code

```
public void parkCar(Car car) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        if (cars[i] == null) {
            cars[i] = car;
            break; // do not allocate other null spaces with same car, leave space for the next cars
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit** as suggested by [Mshnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3267497/mshnik) simply you can return instead of break. Post loop can be used to handle the exceptional flow, i.e. incase there is not vacant space left for parking.

```
public void parkCar(Car car) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        if (cars[i] == null) {
            cars[i] = car;
            return; // do not allocate other null spaces with same car, leave space for the next cars
        }
    }

   System.out.println("Sorry, no space left for parking");
  //here you can add code so as to see a parking space at some other place , may be you can have a 2-d array with each row representing a parking space. 
}
```

Comment: `return` works as well as `break` here, and is a bit better style. The point of a method called `parkCar` is clearly to park a car, so once that is done the method should be terminated. Additionally, the post-loop area is then reserved for exception handling (i.e. there weren't any open spaces).

Comment: @anna you are most welcome, you can mark the answer as 'accepted' in case answer fully satisfies you and solves your query completely... :)

Comment: @anna also see the usage of 'return', it was suggested by Mshnik, I included it in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have two types of objects to keep track of: set of empty spots and set of cars willing to park.

`parkCar` deals with empty spots correctly, `if (cars[i]==null)cars[i] = car;`, but it doesn't check how many cars willing to park are out there. Instead you need `if (cars[i]==null && setOfCarsWillingToPark.size() > 0)`.

Your method only parks one car, so you should use `break` when one spot was discovered. Since this is a method you should just use `return`.